# Appropriate statistical test for comparing student test scores

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

A single class of students were given a session on a subject. This subject was split in example A (taught using active method) and example B (taught using passive method). Students were examined on the topic prior to the session, immediately afterward, and one week afterward. The test was identical each time. The test was anonymous, so I am unable to assess individuals test scores.

I'm trying to find the appropriate tests to assess the following hypotheses:

1. Students' marks will be higher for example A than example B (taking into account prior knowledge).
2. Long-term retention (after one week) will be better for example A than example B.

I'm a little confused which statistical tests would be appropriate as I don't have paired values, so am just assessing the class in general.

Any ideas? TIA